# How obtain the time taken for the method to be executed TESTNG

Tags: java, testng

How obtain the time taken for the method to be executed TESTNG?

Sample test:

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 100, invocationCount = 100)
public void testA() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

It  will run 100 times. I want to obtain the time taken for the method  testA  for every execution.

Answer (score 5):

Usually this information is provided in TestNG report.

If you need this time while running test suite, in @AfterMethod use [ITestResult](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITestResult.html) object:

```
@AfterMethod
public void getRunTime(ITestResult tr) {
    long time = tr.getEndMillis() - tr.getStartMillis();
}
```

---

Related:
[TestNG Dependency injection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection)

Comment: Long a=result.getEndMillis()-result.getStartMillis()  use teh method , I could get the time now. Thanks you !

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out. I was typing too quickly. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Can I have the live time duration while a test method is executing ? I basically need to hit an api call to renew user access token based on a time limit of 5 mins.